# Empty element positions itself differently from one with content?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a fixed-size `<button>` next to an input. I tried the following:

```
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit">S</button>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
input {
  height: 38px;
  width: 50%;
}
button {
  height: 38px;
  width: 38px;
}
```

This works fine, but when I removed the inner HTML from the button, the button moved itself up by 13px:

```
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

[image: Button moved]

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/7btjsowd/3/)

I'm really curious at this point what's causing this behaviour and is there anything I can do prevent it (other than adding e.g. a `&nbsp;` or a `:before` to the button)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements are aligned by its baselines by default. In your first example, there is no text, so the baseline of the element is determined by the element itself as a box, meaning the browser "sees" the baseline as the bottom of the element.

Take a look at [`vertical-align`'s possible values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) and see what best suits your needs. `middle`, `top` and `bottom` will all work here since your button is the same size as the input, but choose based on your future plans.

Answer (score 1):

Use vertical-align property to change the alignment

```
button {
  height: 38px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width: 38px;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7btjsowd/4/)